# Hide a Checkbox in mvc4 without using style

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to set the visibility of a checkbox to false without using style in mvc3.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Eng, new { @id = "chkEnergy1", @value = "true", @class = "chkEnergy",@visible=false }).I have given like this but its not working
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to output the checkbox at all or you don't want to use an external CSS?

Comment: Could you instead use [@Html.HiddenFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor(v=vs.108).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Eng, new { @id = "chkEnergy1", @value = "true", @class = "chkEnergy",@style = "display:none;" }).
```